# Monitor Volume Size on Amazon EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was wondering if it is possible to automatically monitor the usage percentage on a EBS volume in aws (the volume I wish to monitor is attached to a instance). Perhaps this can be done with alarms in cloudwatch? For example, I need to be alerted if the volume usage percentage reaches 95%. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amazon won't do this for you - from their point of view an EBS volume is just a bunch of blocks

In the past I've done this by writing a script (run via a cronjob) that checked the amount of free space on the volume and posted it to cloudwatch (which was setup to trigger an alarm past a certain threshold).

Amazon also provide such a [script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html)

Comment: Yeah I figured something like that. Thanks.

Comment: adding a link to an example script would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provide a perl script which can be used to create CW alerts/metrics as detailed here
https://serverfault.com/questions/439928/making-alarm-in-disk-space-using-cloudwatch

Answer (score 0):

An update on this question.

All the answers are now outdated and the links posted show **deprecated** procedures.

The new way to get disk usage in EC2, is to use the unified cloudwatch agent which has pre-built capabilities to extract metrics from EC2, if configured correctly.
You can follow the instruction from these docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

Answer (score -1):

Now you can actually create a cloudwatch alarm and find the EBS Volume and create a metric using freeDiskSpace and have it send notifications to the SNS.

Comment: As for now FreeDiskSPace is not a metric that is supported for EBS volumes.

Comment: Jan 2022: There is no such metric called `freeDiskSpace`